# Dominant RGB analysis video

Tags: python, opencv, for-loop, rgb, video-processing

I'm trying to find the most dominant RGB color in each frame of a video (made with piCamera) and save this into a csv (or matrix, anything i can use outside of the for loop). But everytime I go out of the for loop, it only saves the last frame RGB data.
I've tried: with open("filename.csv", 'w') as f: but I got a blank file; and export.to_csv only saved the last rgb value. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

'''

```
while True:
        
        _, frame = cap.read()
        

        #Check whether there are still frames to analyze
        if frame is not None:
            RGB = frame
            # Display the resulting frame
            shape = frame.shape
            RGBS = RGB.reshape((shape[0]*shape[1],3))

            num_clusters = 1
            clusters = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
            clusters.fit(RGBS)
                
            # count the dominant colors and put them in "buckets"
            histogram = make_histogram(clusters)
            # then sort them, most-common first
            combined = zip(histogram, clusters.cluster_centers_)
            combined2 = sorted(values, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

            # finally, we'll output a graphic showing the colors in order
            bars = []
            hsv_values=[]
            rgb_values = []
            for index, rows in enumerate(combined2):
                bar, rgb, hsv = make_bar(100, 100, rows[1])
                #print(rgb)
                #rgb_values.append(rgb)
                #hsv_values.append(hsv)
                #bars.append(bar)
      
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key == 27:
                break
        # End the loop if there is no more frame to analyse     
        else:
            break
```

'''

Comment: What happens if you move `bars = []`, `hsv_values=[]`, `rgb_values = []` all to be declared before the While loop? It seems to me like `bars = []` will reset that array each time the While loop runs.

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work. I still get an empty csv when i put this after the code:
    data = pd.DataFrame(rgb_values)
    export_csv = data.to_csv (f'{filename}_rough.csv', index = None, header=True)

Comment: Ah nevermind, I made a type error, it works perfectly!! Thank you!!